# jQuery loading <script> but not evaluating the same under AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

I'm developing a single page application which I intend to keep as much modular as possible. Also, it'll be a rather large application, so, I intend to load the controllers only when the associated view is loaded. For achieving the same I have structured my code in the following way:

app.js

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngRoute']).config(function($httpProvider) { 
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = "XMLHttpRequest";
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";
});
```

route.js

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/user/login", {
        templateUrl: "/user/login.html",
        controller: "LoginCtrl"
    });
});
```

user/login.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/user/login.js"></script>
<div>
    <!-- Complete Login Form -->
</div>
```

js/user/login.js

```
app.controller("LoginCtrl", function() {
    // Login related functionality
});
```

Now, the problem that I'm facing is that the `login.html` template is loading properly. Also, the request for `login.js` is being sent and the response is received successfully. But, still I'm getting error from AngularJS saying that the `LoginCtrl` is `undefined`. I researched on the same and found that including jQuery solves the problem, but that didn't happen. I tried putting a simple alert in the `login.js` file, but the popup also didn't appear.

Any help is much appreciated in the matter.

Comment: did the answer worked??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change the location of login controller

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/user/login", {
        templateUrl: "/user/login.html",
         //controller: "LoginCtrl" // remove this
    });
});
```

and replace html like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/user/login.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
    <!-- Complete Login Form -->
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but the error is still there. The problem is probably because the time at which AngularJS trying to instantiate the controller, the reference to controller doesn't exists in the application.

Comment: Your suggestion did work, there was one other thing to be done. As the controller is coming via an AJAX call, it had to bind lazily using `$controllerProvider`. Thanks for your help!!!